# WMI - Using a non admin account to query server

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmi-query

I want to collect performance data from a Windows 2008 R2 Server with PowerShell.
For this task, I want to use a non admin account.
My problem is now, that I´m getting back a empty object ($WMIService).
There is no error message when I´m executing my script.
When I´m using a account with admin rights, everything is perfect.
So I think, permissions are missing for the non admin account.

How can I fix my problem?

My configuration for the WMIService account:

- Enable remote WMI requests [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787533%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- Enable DCOM calls [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa393266.aspx)

My script:

```
$ServiceCred = Get-Credential
$AdminCred= Get-Credential

$WMIService = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory  -ComputerName servername -Credential $ServiceCred
$WMIAdmin = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory  -ComputerName servername -Credential $AdminCred

$WMIService (Empty)
$WMIAdmin (Perfect)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! The user must also be in the Performance Monitor Users group.

My working configuartion:

- Enable remote WMI requests technet
- Enable DCOM calls msdn
- Added account to the **Performance Monitor Users** group

Answer (score 1):

You should set the [appropriate permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771551.aspx) for your non admin account.

Comment: Thanks for you comment! I know this site, look at my links. My account use for the root and subfolder the permissions -Enable Account and - Remote Enable

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a [this](http://www.poweradmin.com/help/enableWMI.aspx) guide, it may help. Make sure you enabled *Remote Enable* on your user configuration.